# Wiring Feather Huzzah ESP8266 to Monochrome 1.3" 128x64 LCD

Tags: lcd, adafruit

I'm new to Arduino and the pinouts for the Adafruit 938 LCD doesn't seem to match the pinouts that I looked up for the Huzzah ESP8266.

Does anyone know the proper pinout for this display and the Huzzah?

Comment: At the Adafruit site it says: (for the 938) The driver chip, SSD1306 can communicate in two ways: I2C or SPI.  And (for the Huzzah) 9 x GPIO (3.3V logic), which can also be used for I2C or SPI.  I think the problem you are faced with is that the Huzzah has programmable pins that can be configured for many things.  Two of which are, evidently, I2C or SPI.  BTW, this isn't necessarily an easy 1st Arduino project.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just as easy as connecting certain wires to certain pins? I just am confused with the pinout, thats all..

Comment: You may need pull up resistors for the I2C bus.  I2C was designed so all devices are open collector drivers so the bus needs at least 1 pull up resistor on the data line and 1 on the clock line.  That said, sometimes the pull up resistors have been added by the people who designed the PCB.  For SPI I believe you don't need pull up resistors.  However the labeling can get confusing (MISO connects to MOSI & the other MOSI connects to the other MISO).  As for the pin-outs, the same pins might be used for more than 1 feature.  You need to sift through the data sheets and figure this out.